# multiple definitions of stochastic node binomial mixture model

Tags: winbugs

I know that this is a question that has been asked before and I have looked at the answers, but they don't seem to apply to my question. I've written a binomial mixture model that includes the usage of a covariate in WinBUGS. The model is syntactically correct and the data loads fine, but I get the error 'multiple definitions of node 'lambda[1]'. Lambda is not defined within the data and it's subscripted to provide an estimate for every year there is data.

My code is the following:

```
model {

#Priors 

for (k in 1:7) {
lambda[k]~dnorm(0,0.01)
p[k]~dunif(0,1)
}

alpha0~dunif(-10,10)
alpha1~dunif(-10,10)
beta0~dunif(-10,10)
beta1~dunif(-10,10)

#Likelihood
#Ecological model for true abundance (process model)
for (k in 1:7) {                                                #Loop over years
    lambda[k]<-exp(alpha.lam[k])
    for (i in 1:R) {                                        #Loop over R sites
        N[i,k]~dpois(lambda[k])                  #Abundance
        log(lambda[k])<-alpha0+alpha1*well[i,k]

        #Observation model for replicated counts
        for (j in 1:T) {                #Loop over repeated counts within a year
            y[i,j,k] ~dbin(p[k],N[i,k])                 #Detection
            p[k]<-exp(lp[k])/(1+exp(lp[k]))
            lp[k]<-beta0+beta1*well[i,k]

            #Assess model fit using Chi-squared discrepancy
            #Compute fit statistic "E" for observed data
            eval[i,j,k]<-p[k]*N[i,k]                    #Expected values
            E[i,j,k]<-pow((y[i,j,k]-eval[i,j,k]),2)/(eval[i,j,k]+0.5)

            #Generate replicate data and compute fit stats for them
            y.new[i,j,k]~dbin(p[k],N[i,k])
            E.new[i,j,k]<-pow((y.new[i,j,k]-eval[i,j,k]),2)/(eval[i,j,k]+0.5)

            }#j

        }#i

}#k

#Derived and other quantities

for(k in 1:7) {

totalN[k]<-sum(N[,k])                   #Total pop. size across all sites
mean.abundance[k]<-exp(alpha.lam[k])

}


fit<-sum(E[,,])
fit.new<-sum(E.new[,,])
}

#Data
list(R=669,T=3)
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error. Many thanks in advance.